# Why does my method say it must return a type string and gives me an error even though my method does return a type string

Tags: java

```
 
   public static String grade(){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your letter grade");
    String grade = s.next();
    String a = "Your grade is between 93.0 and 100";
    String b = "Your grade is between 83.0 and 93.0";
    String c = "Your grade is between 73.0 and 83.0";
    String d = "Your grade is between 63.0 and 73.0";
    String f = "Your grade is less than 63.0";
    if(grade.equals('A')){
        return a;
    }else if (grade.equals('B')){
        return b;
    }else if (grade.equals('C')){
        return c;
    }else if (grade.equals('D')){
                return d;
    }else if (grade.equals('F')){
        return f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include the full source code of your class (see [mcve]). Also edit the tags of your question, since this isn't a HTML related question.

Comment: What does the method return when someone enters `'G'` as a grade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your method is that it misses a default return type. If you enter a value which is not `A-F` your method does not return a String.

So either throw an exception or return a default value (e.g. `null`):

```
if (grade.equals("A")) {
    return a;
} else if (grade.equals("B")) {
    return b;
} else if (grade.equals("C")) {
    return c;
} else if (grade.equals("D")) {
    return d;
} else if (grade.equals("F")) {
    return f;
}
throw new IllegalArgumentException("The value you entered is not valid");
```

Beside that you are comparing a `String` to a `char` which you should not do, because that are different types. So use `"` instead of `'` like I showed in the snippet above.

At the end you can also use a `switch` instead of all that `else if` statements:

```
switch (grade) {
    case "A":
        return a;
    case "B":
        return b;
    case "C":
        return c;
    case "D":
        return d;
    case "F":
        return f;
}
return "some default";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return null, empty ("") or a default String for the method. Because, nested if conditions are like a separate function and return values for those are local variables (valid only inside condition) for that if or else if condition. Correct your code in the following way.

```
public static String grade() {

    Scanner s = new Scanner([System.in](https://System.in));

    System.out.println("Please enter your letter grade");

    String grade = [s.next](https://s.next)();

    String a = "Your grade is between 93.0 and 100";

    String b = "Your grade is between 83.0 and 93.0";

    String c = "Your grade is between 73.0 and 83.0";

    String d = "Your grade is between 63.0 and 73.0";

    String f = "Your grade is less than 63.0";



    if(grade.equals('A')) {

        return a;

    } else if (grade.equals('B')) {

        return b;

    } else if (grade.equals('C')) {

        return c;

    } else if (grade.equals('D')) {

         return d;

    } else if (grade.equals('F')) {

        return f;

    }

    return null; // or return f;
}
```